# ¿Existe una manera estándar de limpiar la pantalla en C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows

Hola soy nuevo programando en general; quisiera saber si hay una manera estándar de limpiar la pantalla. Sé que se puede utilizar system(cls) en windows o system (clear) en linux. Pero, ¿Hay una manera de hacerlo independientemente del sistema operativo? ya sea Windows, FreeBSD, Linux (también Android)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Una de las repuestas mas breves que he escrito nunca: **no, no la hay**.

Ni C ni C++ tienen nada parecido al concepto de `pantalla`. Tienen *corrientes* de entrada/salida, que son *cosas* abstractas no asociadas a ningún tipo de dispositivo físico. Puede que esten asociadas a un *terminal*, o puede que no.

Lo que si hay son librerías mas o menos *portables* para el manejo de *terminales*. Un *terminal* es un ente software/hardware que interpreta de cierta forma ciertas secuencias de caracteres. En Linux, en modo texto, es del tipo `linux`. En modo gráfico, pues suele ser `xterm` o `xterm-color`.

En Windows, creo que la `ventana MS-DOS` tiene soporte, entre otras, para *terminales* `ANSI` y alguna mas.

Recuerda siempre que esto no es seguro: si yo lanzo tu programa así:

> tuPrograma > miarchivo.txt

¿ De que tipo es esa terminal ? No es mas que un archivo, y cualquier secuencia de códigos de control que envíes se guardará *tal cual*, por supuesto, sin tener el menor efecto sobre la *pantalla*.

Buscando en google [`portable terminal lib`](https://www.google.es/search?q=portable%20terminal%20lib) salen unas cuentas. Puedes hecharles un vistazo a voluntad :-)

Otro punto de vista es tratar directamente con las funciones del programa *terminal* que estés usando: la consola de Windows, el emulador de terminal preferido en Linux. Así **si** que puedes interactuar directamente con la *pantalla*, independientemente de posibles redirecciones de entrada/salida ... pero eso es aún menos portable: ahora dependemos exactamente del API del programa elegido.

Answer (score 10):

Yo tenía el mismo problema en la universidad y la solución más viable que encontré fue crear una función que limpiara la ventana de la terminal independientemente del sistema operativo.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  #include<windows.h>
#endif  

void limpiar_pantalla()
{
  #ifdef _WIN32
    system("cls");
  #else
    system("clear");
  #endif
}
```

el [`#ifdef`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/122151/21) es un comando del pre-procesador, y es una forma común de *excluir* o *incluir* partes del código fuente que se *entrega* finalmente al compilador, de manera condicional. En este caso, el símbolo
`_WIN32` está definido solamente en *Windows* y con la construcción utilizada el compilador verá, por ejmplo, la instrucción `#include<windows.h>` solo si es Windows. En una compilación para linux, es como si esa línea del fuente no existiera.

En la escuela me hice mi pequeña biblioteca con funciones similares para poder usarlas en windows y otros sistemas operativos. Podrías considerarlo por si es que esto es algo que vas a repetir constantemente.

Comment: Sería bueno que explicaras que hace el #ifdef, no todo le mundo lo sabe. Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Si estas programando en Windows, podes llamar la funcion system.

```
system("cls");
```

Tambien podes ir la siguiente dirección: https://support.microsoft.com/es-ar/help/99261/how-to-performing-clear-screen-cls-in-a-console-application

Donde se muestra como implementar una función cls() en C.

Comment: -1 porque no es **independientemente del sistema operativo** como lo pidieron